# Dockerfile FROM command - Does it always download from Docker Hub?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I just started working with docker this week and came across a 'dockerfile'. I was reading up on what this file does, and the official documentation basically mentions that the FROM keyword is needed to build a "base image". These base images are pulled from Docker hub, or downloaded from there.

Silly question - Are base images always pulled from docker hub?

If so and if I understand correctly I am assuming that running the dockerfile to create an image is not done very often (only when needing to create an image) and once the image is created then the image is whats run all the time?

So the dockerfile then can be migrated to which ever enviroment and things can be set up all over again quickly?

Pardon the silly question I am just trying to understand the over all flow and how dockerfile fits into things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the local (on your host) Docker daemon (already) has a copy of the container image (i.e. it's been `docker pull`'d) specified by `FROM` in a `Dockerfile` then it's cached and won't be repulled.

Container images include a tag (be wary of ever using `latest`) and the image name e.g. `foo` combined with the tag (which defaults to `latest` if not specified) is the full name of the image that's checked i.e. if you have `foo:v0.0.1` locally and `FROM:v0.0.1` then the local copy is used but `FROM foo:v0.0.2` will pull `foo:v0.0.2`.

There's an implicit `docker.io` prefix i.e. `docker.io/foo:v0.0.1` that references the Docker registry that's being used.

You could repeatedly `docker build` container images on the machines where the container is run but this is inefficient and the more common mechanism is that, once a container image is built, it is pushed to a registry (e.g. DockerHub) and then pulled from there by whatever machines need it.

There are many container registries: DockerHub, [Google Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry), [Quay](https://quay.io/) etc.

There are tools other than `docker` that can be used to interact with containers e.g. (Red Hat's) [Podman](https://podman.io/).

Comment: On this note @DazWilkin, can I ask another question to expand my knowledge. Say I create docker image via a dockerfile. Then due to some error docker build exits without executing all commands. 

Now, instead of rebuilding image, what if go in iterative mode and make changes via command line. Say install packages. 
Does docker sync this image to the intended push location (and can I push it forcefully) with the latest changes done to in the interactive mode. 
Or it just discards those changes as we exit the iterative mode in the local terminal.

Comment: Please don't ask follow-up questions in comments. If it's another question, create it as another question.

Comment: It's not good practice to make interactive changes. A key benefit of containers is that they're reproducible builds through a Dockerfile. If you must do it, you can use [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/)

Comment: @DazWilkin - Thank you for the very layman docker-101 explanation :) Just wanted to add in addition - So if I have this straight after doing the "docker build", I install what I want and am happy with the container image and I call it "greatstuff_v01" I would then push this to DockerHub? Is it fair to assume DockerHub has a "private" mechanism and lets say another machine needs to use this container then I can pull this "greatstuff_v01" private container image down to that machine and its good to go? And no one else can see it unless I allow them? Pardon the basic questions!

Comment: @rodneyc8063 that's correct. Container registries support authentication to permit private and, if wanted, public container images.